# Cant figure out suddenly im getting error in Eclipse Android " Source not found " why?

Tags: android, eclipse

I had a ListView so I deleted it in the main.xml designer and it was automatically removed from the main.xml code also.

Then I added a spinner to the designer which added automatically to the main.xml code too.
In my program I deleted all uses for the ListView and added using the spinner.

Then I did a debug on one line and when I run my application in Debug mode and select *yes* then I'm getting an error in the debug window in red saying `Source not found`.

And I have a button I can click: `Edit a source lookup path`

I'm not sure where the problem is and how to fix it. 5 minutes ago before I removed the ListView and added the spinner in the designer it worked perfectly.

This is the main.xml code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSpeak"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10" >

        <requestFocus />

    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

And this is my java class code:

```
package com.testotspeech;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Locale;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class AndroidTestToSpeechActivity extends Activity implements
        TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    private TextToSpeech tts;
    private Button btnSpeak;
    private EditText txtText;
    private String array_spinner[];
    private ArrayList<String> itemsList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Log.i("----------",Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        itemsList.add(Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
        array_spinner = new String[itemsList.size()];
        tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
        btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
        txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

        // button on click event
        btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                speakOut();
            }

        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        // Don't forget to shutdown tts!
        if (tts != null) {
            tts.stop();
            tts.shutdown();
        }
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    public void onInit(int status) {

        if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {

            int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.ENGLISH);

            if (result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA
                    || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED) {
                Log.e("TTS", "This Language is not supported");
            } else {
                btnSpeak.setEnabled(true);
                speakOut();

            }

        } else {
            Log.e("TTS", "Initilization Failed!");
        }

    }

    private void speakOut() {

        String text = txtText.getText().toString();
        tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
    }
}
```

What could be causing the error?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** here is the stacktrace log, only errors in red:

```
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testotspeech/com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestToSpeechActivity.java:30)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
06-04 20:20:05.609: E/AndroidRuntime(8567):     ... 11 more
06-04 20:22:54.219: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:24:32.509: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:25:45.439: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:32:49.439: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:33:06.109: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.109: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.119: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:06.119: E/lights(127): write ok string=1,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.129: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.129: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:06.149: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.159: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.159: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:06.169: E/lights(127): write ok string=1,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.169: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:06.169: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:09.179: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:09.179: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:09.179: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:09.189: E/lights(127): write ok string=1,len=1
06-04 20:33:09.189: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:09.189: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.testotspeech/com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2787)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2803)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:135)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2136)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at com.testotspeech.AndroidTestToSpeechActivity.onCreate(AndroidTestToSpeechActivity.java:30)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1069)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2751)
06-04 20:33:16.309: E/AndroidRuntime(8748):     ... 11 more
06-04 20:33:16.339: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.349: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.349: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:16.349: E/lights(127): write ok string=1,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.349: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.359: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:16.559: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.569: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.579: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:16.579: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.579: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.579: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:16.629: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.639: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.639: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:16.639: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.639: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:16.649: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:18.789: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:18.789: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:18.789: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:18.789: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:18.799: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:18.799: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:23.009: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:23.019: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:23.019: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:23.019: E/lights(127): write ok string=1,len=1
06-04 20:33:23.029: E/lights(127): write ok string=0,len=1
06-04 20:33:23.029: E/lights(127): write ok string=0 0,len=3
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367): Writing exception to parcel
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/download from pid=316, uid=10007 requires android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:277)
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:155)
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:134)
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-04 20:33:23.049: E/SwitchUsbSettings(316): Error when query download provider. error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/download from pid=316, uid=10007 requires android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367): Writing exception to parcel
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367): java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/download from pid=316, uid=10007 requires android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceReadPermission(ContentProvider.java:277)
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.bulkQuery(ContentProvider.java:155)
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:134)
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:288)
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/DatabaseUtils(367):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
06-04 20:33:23.149: E/SwitchUsbSettings(316): Error when query download provider. error: java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: reading com.android.providers.downloads.DownloadProvider uri content://downloads/download from pid=316, uid=10007 requires android.permission.ACCESS_DOWNLOAD_MANAGER
06-04 20:33:56.369: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:38:30.539: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:50:48.819: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 20:51:59.019: E/ActivityManager(127): fail to set top app changed!
06-04 23:01:32.909: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:02:23.029: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:04:03.339: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:07:23.899: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:09:54.619: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:14:04.959: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:16:35.439: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
06-04 23:20:58.319: E/jdwp(9122): Failed sending reply to debugger: Broken pipe
06-04 23:21:36.259: E/Tethering(127): active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
```

Comment: please post StackTrace. Also restarting Eclipse and do a "Project->clean" helps most of the time in such cases

Comment: Rafael T , Restarting Eclipse didnt help also the cleaning didnt help. And how do i post a StackTrace i mean where do i see the StackTrace in the Eclipse ?

Comment: Link to the text file with the stacktrace the full stacktrace: http://www.scribd.com/doc/95909529/Stack-Trace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your Null pointer is telling you, that your ArrayList itemsList is Null, and not initialized. try it like this:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    Log.i("----------",Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
    itemsList = new ArrayList<String>();
    //here you never initialized ItemsList before, and get a nullpointer
    itemsList.add(Arrays.toString(Locale.getAvailableLocales()));
    array_spinner = new String[itemsList.size()];
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
    btnSpeak = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSpeak);
    txtText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtText);

    // button on click event
    btnSpeak.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            speakOut();
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Rafael T Thanks silly me. I know c# and forgot to make an instance for the arrayList. Silly me. Sorry.

Comment: happens to all of us :) Importand is, that you learn from mistakes you made once. Also the ability of reading stack-traces can save you much time.Try to get familar with them, and if you're stuck, you're very welcome on Stackoverflow